# How long does Redgard last after open? How do I store it for long term (6-7 months) so I can reuse it?

Tags: waterproofing

I have used a half of the bucket of Redgard waterproof membrane liquid and I would like to store the rest of it for another 6 months or so till I do the other bathroom. What is the correct way to store it ? How long can I store it ?

Answer (score 3):

Pour into a smaller container.   You don’t want a 1/2 can of air to be drying out the product.   Some fit  a piece of plastic Down on top of the liquid to seal the liquid away from the air in can

Comment: I am wondering if the material would seal itself. The surface will solidify in contact with the air and it will form a crust. The rest of it should stay protected.
Of course you need to keep the bucket in a fixed position for that time othersie the crust might break and more material will be wasted
Since this is waterproof there should be no humidity gradient from the liquid Redgard below the crust and the drier air gap that is under the lid.

Comment: Yes it wil skin over.  But that wastes the drying agents in the product.  The remaining product under the skin will be diminished in quality

Comment: Suggesting that the quality will be diminished without quantifying that or giving any evidence appears to be your supposition.  Do you have literally anything that backs up that claim?  I don't see how the drying agents are "wasted" since they're added to chemically do their job and get used up drying the skin. and then there's no more O2 or H2O (or whatever promotes the drying agents)...

Comment: I just had a half bucket go bad on me, I’d recommend the plastic… that’s what I’m doing with my next one. There was no crust that formed on top the whole thing turned to one glob

Comment: @bvargo I have my own and others  experience to back up my claim see the recent comment by Kevin.